# Symfony links on Secure Page

Tags: php, security, symfony, ssl, hyperlink

I have a section of my Symfony app that I made secure because I handle payments on that page. Being a good SO user I did my research first and set that up using access_control as follows:

```
- { path: /orders, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https}
```

The problem is with the links to other internal pages on my site. My order page inherits some base templates which contain headers/footer etc. These have links to other sections of my site. But since my order page is secure, it's also securing the links to other pages (https).

The base template links use the Twig 'path' function as follows'

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Home</a>
```

Is there a way to secure the order page but make it so the links to other internal pages aren't using https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must force the route that you don't want secured to use http

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html

Comment: Yes, that was the first solution I came to also. But for a site that has a lot of routes this seems like a real pain to force each one individually. But I guess if that's the only way...

Comment: Could I use a regex to say 'paths that don't have /order in it use http'?